# Proper usage of Retrofit + RxJava's combineLatest

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

I want to perform 2 network calls asynchronously - I'm using Retrofit+RxJava to accomplish this.  This logic is from a simple Runner class to test out the solution.  NOTE: This concerns mostly RxJava on the server-side.

My code looks like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Api api = ...;

  Observable.combineLatest(
      api.getStates(),
      api.getCmsContent(),
      new Func2<List<States>, CmsContent, String>() {
        @Override public String call(List<State> states, CmsContent content) {
          ...
          return "PLACEHOLDER";
        }
      })
      .observeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
      .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
        @Override public void onCompleted() {
          System.out.println("COMPLETED");
        }

        @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
          System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override public void onNext(String s) {
          // I don't care what's returned here
        }
      });
}
```

Three questions:

1. Is `Observable.combineLatest` the best operator to use when you want to execute multiple REST calls asynchronously and proceed when all calls have finished?
2. My `Func2` implementation currently returns a `String`.  After the 2 API calls execute, I'll process the results within the  `Func2#call()` method. I don't care what is returned - there must be a better way to handle this, though - am I correct?
3. The API calls are correctly executed with the code above. But the `main` method doesn't complete with the proper `Process finished with exit code 0` when I run the program.  What could be causing the code to hang?

**UPDATE - *2015-05-14***

Based on the recommendation, I've changed the logic to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Api api = ...;

  Observable.zip(
      api.getStates(),
      api.getCmsContent(),
      new Func2<List<States>, CmsContent, Boolean>() {
        @Override public Boolean call(List<State> states, CmsContent content) {
          // process data
          return true;
        }
      })
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .toBlocking()
      .first();
}
```

This looks like the solution I was looking for.  I'm going to use it for some time to see if I run into any troubles.

Answer (score 5):

1) If you know you'll have a single value on both paths, it is as good as `zip`.

2) What would you like to do? You'll get the pair of values in your `Func2` and if you don't really care about what travels with `onNext`, return a value of your chosing.

3) `Schedulers.immediate()` is not a real scheduler in some sense and is quite prone to same-pool deadlock scenarios. You really don't need to use it. If you want to block the main thread until the async work is finished, use `toBlocking().first()` for example.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my code sample with your recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

1) No the best is to use `zip()`. Combine latest is good if one of the two (or more) apis are returning "slower" different results/ it has the essence of caching.

2) Fun2 facilitates merging the results. It better (architecture-wise) to process the result either in the onNext() or onError(). You can use a simple `Pair<T,Y>` class to pass the results from the Func2 to the onNext().

3) Nothing's wrong. The result as said should be processed in the onNext() and not in the onComplete. According to [Retrofit's source code](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/cce2ece9b2d43c6033deecc0142e2091f63757a1/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java#L240) the results are passed only (of course corectly) in the onNext().

Hope those help.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that I'm about a year late on this but the edit posted by the OP on  2015-05-14 doesn't meet his original requirement:

> I want to perform 2 network calls asynchronously

1. Observables `getStates` and `getCmsContent` will NOT execute concurrently unless they individually subscribe on separate threads. This is a crucial point omitted in his post and none of the previous answer called it out.

   ```
   Observable.fromCallable(() -> doStuff())
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
   ```

As @akarnokd said, in case both streams have single values, `zip` and `combineLatest` behave similarly. The merge function will block until both `getStates` and `getCmsContent` return but like I show above, each of them execute concurrently on separate threads.

2. Another solution depends on the ability to merge the `List<States>` and `CmsContent` as they arrive. Given his code, there's clearly a "data holder" of some sort (not shown) because what he's returning is a `Boolean`, not the merged data. In the following, `forEach` executes concurrently.

   ```
   Observable.just(api.getStates(), api.getCmsContent())
   // subscribe on separate thread as shown previously
   .flatMap(this::buildObservable)
   .toBlocking()
   // executes concurrently
   .forEach(item -> {
       // merge into "data holder"          
   });
   ```

Of course, this code has the issue of not being strongly typed so that's a choice to make.